# SQL Server DEFAULT FOR Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, default-constraint

Why is there a syntax error near 'for' as SQL Server 2012 reports?

Is not DEFAULT FOR syntax available when creating a table, but when altering it? Here is a tutorial about altering a table and adding a default constraint [link](http://www.tutorialsqlserver.com/Create/Default-Value-in-Sql-Server.htm), but I can't get it right when creating it.

```
CREATE TABLE Meal (
    MealID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    MealName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    IsVege char NOT NULL,
    MealDescription varchar(150) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Ckh_Meal_IsVege
        CHECK (IsVege in ('t', 'f')),
    CONSTRAINT Def_Meal_IsVege
        DEFAUlT ('t') FOR IsVege,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quirk of the [`CREATE TABLE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) syntax that you can only declare a `DEFAULT` constraint inline, as per [StuartLC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23366968/15498). You *can* also create table constraints, but these are only:

```
< table_constraint > ::=
[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] 
{ 
    { PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE } 
        [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] 
        (column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ] ) 
        [ 
            WITH FILLFACTOR = fillfactor 
           |WITH ( <index_option> [ , ...n ] ) 
        ]
        [ ON { partition_scheme_name (partition_column_name)
            | filegroup | "default" } ] 
    | FOREIGN KEY 
        ( column [ ,...n ] ) 
        REFERENCES referenced_table_name [ ( ref_column [ ,...n ] ) ] 
        [ ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ] 
        [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ] 
        [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] 
    | CHECK [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] ( logical_expression ) 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add it immediately after the column definition and lose the `FOR`:

```
IsVege char NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Def_Meal_IsVege DEFAULT 't'
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c058)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Meal (
    MealID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    MealName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    IsVege char NOT NULL,
    MealDescription varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Meal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MealID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Meal] ADD  CONSTRAINT [Ckh_Meal_IsVege]  DEFAULT (('f')) FOR [IsVege]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Meal] ADD  CONSTRAINT [Def_Meal_IsVege]  DEFAULT (('t')) FOR [IsVege]
GO
```